# Leaflet: Add popup onto a layer using GeoJSON

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a layer that have several circleMarker from a GeoJSON.

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
  radius: 8,
  fillColor: "#ff7800",
  color: "#000",
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.8
};

L.geoJSON(someGeojsonFeature, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

How can I add an popup on to each circleMarker where user can click on each circle to get a popup?

Comment: You can use the .bindPopup() function described in the leaflet [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/).

Comment: How to put the .bindPopup() on the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
var geojsonMarkerOptions = {
  radius: 8,
  fillColor: "#ff7800",
  color: "#000",
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  fillOpacity: 0.8
};

L.geoJSON(someGeojsonFeature, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      var mypopup = L.popup().setContent("latlng: " + latlng);
      var mymarker = L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions);

      mymarker.bindPopup(mypopup);
      return mymarker;               
  }
}).addTo(map);
```